# Program Compiles Without Error, but Segfaults During Execution

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

The following code compiles just fine but when I run it, it gets to the while loop and then `SegFaults`. The input file is a CSV file. What this program is supposed to take data from a CSV file and parse it into a structure, which is then sent to a function that prints it in a particular format to stdout.

Comment: First thing: add `if(argc < 2) /* error */`

Comment: 'Program Compiles Without Error, but Segfaults During Execution' - you should be aware that's normal behaviour.  'I need to turn this in by 11:59 tonight and I have no idea how to fix it' - youi should have allowed enough time for testing and debugging.  Such acitivity typically takes much longer than writing the code and getting it to compile.

Comment: Your airPdata is only pointer and then it's null, and then the values of this struct are also only pointers.

Comment: It sould be airPdata *airport = malloc(sizeof(airPdata));

Comment: @WeatherVane can you explain what that means? I'm new to coding.

Comment: @Andrew thanks I'll give that a try

Comment: @KevinHoran you can't be that new if you managed to write and format the code as-is.

Comment: @MartinJames it doesn't help to reprimand me for procrastination. I already know that I'm low on time. If you're going to help then help, otherwise don't bother posting.

Comment: @KevinHoran it means you should check there really is an `argv[1]` before using it. Even though it was you who (thinks you) supplied it. It may be you misunderstood how this program takes a file name.

Comment: also increase your buffer from 50 to 1024, it's way to small for the amount of data you are using it for

Comment: Also while(fgets(buffer, maxLineLength, ifp) != NULL && strlen(buffer) > 1) will n ot print you nulls on last line with only newline character

Comment: @andrew it's 50 times the number of data fields per line in the csv, which is 19. That should be enough right? Each piece of data isn't more than 50 characters plus a NULL character.

Comment: @KevinHoran you did not supply a test file, so we don't know.  As a general rule, guesstimate you largest data size, add128 and double it.  SO is full of bean-counters who got their buffer sizes wrong:(

Comment: @KevinHoran You mistake advice for procrastination.  You also seem to mistake SO volunteers as a prop for your own poor time management.   Again - leave lots of time for testing/debugging.  Writing code and getting it to compile cleanly is not even half the job.

Comment: Another poor practice is not checking the return value from `strtok` before dereferencing. For example, if the CSV file contains the sequence `",,"` indicating no data at that position (where a default value might be used) `strtok` will consume both the commas, leaving you with a NULL pointer from the last item. Also as you are reading with `fgets` there will (probably) be a newline at the end of the input string, so the delimiter set for `strtok` should be `",\n"`

Comment: @MartinJames Like I said earlier, it doesn't help to say things like that. I UNDERSTAND. The only reason I came to SO is because I didn't know how to debug a Segfault. Even if i wasn't low on time I would be here because I've never come across a segfault before because I've only ever done simple programs in other classes. This is the most complicated one I've done as of yet. If i knew how to upload a secondary file I would. I would also block you if I knew how. Please either help me or go away.

Comment: If you can't yet use a debugger insert an output cue in the code between every other statement, such as `puts("cue 1")` etc. If you use `printf` to do that, ensure it ends with a newline (as `puts` supplies) to ensure the message reaches the terminal before the crash happens. You can then figure out what line caused the segfault and focus on that, by for example, printing out variables' values.

Comment: Also jou free buffer at every loop cycle.

Comment: @ulix good catch.

Comment: @WaetherVane so are you saying put the delimeter as `",\n"` for every `strtok` in my while loop? and would using `puts` or `printf` help me determine where the crash is happening?

Comment: @ulix should I move the free of the buffer to just after the loop then?

Comment: One malloc, one free. Move the free() just after fclose().

Comment: a) yes, b) because if the program outputs `"cue 1"` and then `"cue 2"` and then crashes, you know the segfault happens after you print `"cue 2"` but before you print `"cue 3"` because that line was not reached...

Comment: @WeatherVane alright theres no more segfault and everything works properly except for the control tower portion. its supposed to be a Y or N in the output but it seems to be printing some of the other fields. might just be that I have to change the order of something

Comment: @WeatherVane You said something earlier about checking the return value of `strtok` because of the multiple comma situation. that seems to be the issue. I thought we fixed that with the newline character in the delimiter though.

Comment: `strsep` will detect adjacent commas but `strtok` will skip them all. But you should check the return value of those 2 functions anyway. Robust code test all the available information *especially* user input, otherwise the code falls over when the input is not perfect. So you can either fail gracefully with an appropriate message, or ask for the input to be repeated.

Answer (score 1):

Your airport pointer is null, so when you try to set elements of it, you dereference a null pointer. To fix, either give it automatic storage like so:

```
airPdata airport;
```

and pass it to `printData` like so:

```
printData(&airport)
```

Or allocate it with malloc:

```
airPdata *airport = malloc(sizeof(*airport));
```

But then make sure to `free` it when you are finished with it.

Also, just because your C program compiles does not mean it is correct, as you have seen. C is really unforgiving, especially with regards to memory, so you'll definitely need to pay close attention to how you handle memory, and maybe consider unit testing your program.